# What are the "regulations of Omri"

Tags: history, micah

In [Micah 6:16 (NET)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Micah+6%3A16&version=NET), the text states

> You implement the regulations of Omri, and all the practices of Ahab’s dynasty; you follow their policies.

What policies, practices and regulations is this specifically referring to and what is the issue with these laws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints at what Micah had in mind may be found in the Books of Kings.

Joseph Blenkinsopp, *A History of Prophecy in Israel*, page 115:

> The allusion to "statutes of Omri" and "deeds of Ahab" (Micah 6:16 recalls the condemnation of Manasseh for imitating the much-maligned Ahab in setting up syncretist cults (2 Kings 21:3; cf. 23:4-14). Micah 6:9-16 also parallels Zephaniah in several respects. Both condemn an unnamed city, which must be Jerusalem (Micah 6:9; Zeph. 3:1), and expatiate on the evils of idolatry in general and the cult of Baal in particular.

The text of 2 Kings 21.3 reads:

> For he rebuilt the high places that his father Hezekiah had destroyed; he erected altars for Baal, made a sacred pole, as King Ahab of Israel had done, worshipped all the host of heaven, and served them.

The other text, 2 Kings 23.4-14, describes how ritual objects for Baal and Asherah worship were removed from Jerusalem's temple at a later time.

Micah may or may not have in mind a specific written set of laws from Omri (à la the Code of Hammurabi). The parallelism with 'the works of the house of Ahab' suggests the prophet is referring to a general swath of practices and customs enforced by Omri, Ahab, and their dynasty, practices and customs which consist of worshiping gods alongside or above Yahweh.